# Unwanted bullet/dot in DateTime string from JS using Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, string, datetime

I need to pass a DateTime from script (via ajax) to Controller, however, the date string throws an Exception after converting to DateTime. After investigating the data being passed, I have noticed that the date string has dots/bullets in between when passed via IE. The dots/bullets are absent when passed via Chrome.

I have tried both `new Date().toLocaleString()` as well as `GETDATE()` from the database. Both have the same result.

[image]

Any ideas how to prevent the dots/bullet, and/or, remove it?

IE version is 11.

JS: `$("#hdnTransDate").val(new Date().toLocaleString());`

Controller:

```
var date = String.Empty;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        conn.Open();
    }

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT GETDATE() as [CurrDate]"))
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
               date = reader["CurrDate"] + "";
            }
        }
    }
}

ViewBag.TranDate = date;

return PartialView();
```

Edit: added version of IE, and code used in JS and Controller

Comment: Please show the code that is producing this data - and clarify which version of Internet Exploder you are using (and check if it's running under an emulation of an earlier version)

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, I've updated my inquiry.

Comment: `$("#hdnTransDate").val(new Date().toLocaleString());` doesn't produce that result ... is the problem the string in the browser or on the server?

Comment: @JaromandaX, in the browser. I've tried to get the value of `$("#hdnTransDate")`, and after copying it to rextester, it produced a string with dots.

Comment: Oh, sorry, yeah, I see it now ... it's especially obvious when you `encodeURIComponent(new Date().toLocaleString())` ... results in `"%E2%80%8E01%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E10%E2%80%8E%2F%E2%80%8E2019%E2%80%8E%20%E2%80%8E19%E2%80%8E%3A%E2%80%8E18%E2%80%8E%3A%E2%80%8E05"`

Comment: https://www.csgpro.com/blog/2016/08/a-bad-date-with-internet-explorer-11-trouble-with-new-unicode-characters-in-javascript-date-strings/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's a bug in IE after reading https://www.csgpro.com/blog/2016/08/a-bad-date-with-internet-explorer-11-trouble-with-new-unicode-characters-in-javascript-date-strings/

You could do something like

```js
function ieIsStupidWithDates(d) {
    var fix = function(s) {
        return ('0' + s).substr(-2);
    }
    return (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + d.getHours() + ':' + fix(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + fix(d.getSeconds());
}
console.log(ieIsStupidWithDates(new Date));
```